# How do to know Field is an array? (java.lang.reflect.Field) in Java

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, types, field

I have array from Field:

```
Field[] fields = instance.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

for (Field field : fields){    

if((field.getType() == Integer.class[])||(field.getType() == Object.class[]))
{
//...    
} 

}
```

How do to learn Field is array? (how to know which field is an array (Object[] array)?), Help me, please.

Answer (score 20):

Use [`Class#isArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray%28%29):

```
if (field.getType().isArray()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can call [`isArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray%28%29) on the `Class<T>` object of the field's type. To get the type of the element, call [`getComponentType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType%28%29) method.

```
if((field.getType().isArray()) {
    Class componentType = field.getType().getComponentType();
    ...
}
```